# Thread waiting for user to click something

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, exception, mouselistener

I'm preparing application to play gomoku.

I've created nice looking GUI, now I'm fighting with core engine.

There is a class `GameEngine` which has synchronized methods to make moves.
There are also classes implementing `IClient` interface which are "players".
First thing to do is to implement `PlayerClient` which is connected to the `BoardPanel` and moves when `MouseListener` in`BoardPanel` (representing gomoku board) sais to. I want my application to be open to implement also computer players. That's why it's so complicated.

So... problem:
My `GameEngine` class looks like this:

```
public class GameEngine {
    private IClient blackPlayer;
    private IClient whitePlayer;
    private GameState gameState;

    ...

    public void play() {
        blackPlayer.run();
        whitePlayer.run();
    }

    public synchronized void move(Move move) throws IllegalMoveException {
        gameState.move(move);
        if (move.isBlackMove()){
            whitePlayer.notify();
        }else{
            blackPlayer.notify();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void waitForYourTurn(boolean color){
        try {
            while (gameState.isBlackToMove()!=color) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and my Client class has run() method:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while (gameState.getWinner() == 0) {
            move = null;
            boolean moved = false;
            while (!moved) {
                gameEngine.waitForYourTurn(black);
                try {
                    //waitForPickedMove();
                    gameEngine.move(move);
                    moved = true;
                } catch (IllegalMoveException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In place, where I wrote "//waitForPickedMove()" Client should wait for user to click proper place on the board. So... there is a MouseListener in my Board class:

```
private class MoveMouseListener implements MouseListener {
        @Override
        public synchronized void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (gameState == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (currentMove != null) {
                movePicked();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
```

currentMove is of course move picked by user by clicking board. While movePicked() looks like this:

```
private synchronized void movePicked() {
    if (gameState.isBlackToMove() && blackClient != null) {
        blackClient.notify();
        clearCurrentMove();
    }
    if (!gameState.isBlackToMove() && whiteClient != null) {
        whiteClient.notify();
        clearCurrentMove();
    }
}
```

I tried to put `wait()` in many places. I tried to reverse control and put it into `Board` class, so it invoked methods in Client class (setCurrentMove(Move move)). Unfortunately I can't reach what I want. I always get `IllegalMonitorStateException` or my GUI blocks.

I hope I explained my problem enough. I'd be thankful for any help.

EDIT:

```
public class MockComputerClient implements IClient {
    private GameState gameState;
    private GameEngine gameEngine;
    private boolean black;
    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private boolean myTurn = false;
    private int i = 3;

    public MockComputerClient(GameEngine gameEngine, GameState gameState,
            boolean black) {
        this.gameEngine = gameEngine;
        this.gameState = gameState;
        this.black = black;
        executorService = new ExecutorService();
        executorService.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void enemyMoved() {
        myTurn = true;
        executorService.notify();
    }

    private class ExecutorService implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (gameState.getWinner() == 0) {
                try {
                    while (!myTurn) {
                        wait();
                    }
                    // Hardcoded Moves
                    gameEngine.move(new Move(black, 3, i++));
                    myTurn = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException | IllegalMoveException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm pretty sure that I should synchronize sth, but I don't really know what.

EDIT 2:

```
@Override
    public void enemyMoved() {
        myTurn = true;
        executorService.move();
    }

    private class ExecutorService implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (gameState.getWinner() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Calculating: j= " + j);
                if (j == 3)
                    j = 4;
                else
                    j = 3;

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        public void move() {
            while (myTurn) {
                try {
                    gameEngine.move(new Move(black, j, i++));
                    myTurn = false;
                } catch (IllegalMoveException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: *"That's why it's so complicated."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt with just the multi-threading and mouse clicks.

Comment: Swing.

Well, it's a big appplication with a lot of classes now. I tried to cut out important things.

Multithreading between gameEngine and clients works fine. I tried to hardcode this currentMove. 

Problem occures when I try to wait for GUI. I'm just not sure what should wait for what and where it should be notified.

So basicly i neeed help in implementing this commented:
Move waitForPickedMove()
and notification somhow... not exactly like this in movePicked()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for the Game Engine to constantly occupy a thread, blocking it when there's nothing to do. You should redesign this to be reactive: code executes when there is an event, in the thread where the event handler is executing. Then you won't need any `wait`-`notify` mechanisms.

If you want to allow a Player implementation to take its time without occupying the calling thread, design the API with asynchronicity in mind: `IClient` will have a method representing "other player has moved", which will not return player's move immediately. The `IClient` will be expected to call a method on the Game Engine with its move.

Comment: Could you show me simple example of your method? I think I don't get it. Multithreading is hard until you understand it very well. :)

I mean e.g. simple application where two threads wait for each other and every one of them waits for mouse to be clicked and e.g writes cursor coordinates to the console.

Comment: Your design a-priori couples a Player to a Thread, this is what is wrong. Put a method in IClient that is called when the opposite player has made a move; this can be a `void` method (a classic callback). Also have the Game Engine possess a callback method that receives a move from the Player. The Human player doesn't need a thread of its own---it responds to actions on the GUI. A computer player isn't a thread, either: it may **use a thread internally** to do its processing. When its "opposite player moved" method is called, it submits a task to an ExecutorService, which calculates...

Comment: ... the move and calls the appropriate Game method with its move.

Comment: Thanks fox explaining, now i'll try to implement what you told me. I will write here my reults.

Comment: Ok, I've done it and it works for PlayerClient. Unfortunately I still have a problem with using Runnable class (Executor Service). I still get this IllegalMonitorStateException. I'll edit main post and show you my MockComputerClient class.

Comment: You should not use any `wait` and `notify` in your solution.

Comment: I meant `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`.

Comment: Ech... one more thing. (edited main post once again).

I tried to mock... some move evaluation. So i wanted to process one of move parameters in run() method of Executor thread. But if I invoke run() my application freezes (i can see "Calculating" in console, but GUI is frozen). If run() is commented it works fine, but j is not being evaluated.

Sorry if I make sth stupid, but it was a long night. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Invoking new Thread by this ExecutorService solved my problem.

Comment: No, don't pass a `Thread` into `ExecutorService`. Pass a plain `Runnable`.

Comment: Yes, yes. That's what i ment.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what it is: a lot of pieces.  But it looks like you should synchronize your notify call as described here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would recommend you to you sleep() and notify(). If you want to stop some thread for unknown time give it sleep and when you need it again give it notify().

Comment: Thanks, but it's not that simple here. :)